# Django-Python : invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django. I am trying to build a page which displays all the users who have registered on to my Website.

The logic I tried to use is getting the id of a user in the built-in User Model.

In views.py, I have created a class based view which is a DetailView like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import DetailView

#I have not used a ListView class but I have used a function based View     
def home(request):
    context = {
        'users': User.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'home_page/home.html', context)
    
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostDetailView, UserDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home_page'),
    path('users/<pk>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail'), 
]
```

In home.html, I have added this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

When I clicked on the username it redirects me to *localhost:8000/users/None/* and I get this error:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

Is this the right way to get the is of a user from the User Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostDetailView, UserDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home_page'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail'), 
]
```

The url waits for an integer, so we have to specify this in the url.

Your view to:

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class UserDetailView(View):

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'home_page/user_details.html', locals())
```

I personally don't like using `context`. I use `locals()` which passes the variables present in the method to the template.
Create a new html `user_details.html` file on home_page folder

and your template to:

```
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' pk=user.pk %}">{{ user.username }}</a></h2>
```

Comment: Well, I goth this error  -  Reverse for 'user-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: There is a problem with `href` tag. I've changed my aswer.

Comment: Yeah, so what do I do? Does the User model have ids for every user(I mean integer ids)?

Comment: @Saatwik Yes. Check if now you can see the page with direct input `http://localhost:8000/users/1/ `

Comment: Yes I'm getting it. But when I add `int:pk` I'm getting the NoReverseMatch error

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for user in users %}
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Its user, not users in the loop

Comment: I have used  - 'users': User.objects.all(),

Comment: inside the template tag buddy {{ }}, pls check again, u are using users

Comment: Gotcha changed it but it shows the same error still

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any User(s) yet, the QueryDict will have no elements (i.e. None) which is what I believe the error code is referring to. Once the User(s) have been created, the result should be an Integer (i.e. primary key to the User). In order to bypass this error, check whether the QueryDict has any elements before your for loop i.e.

```
{% if users %}
    {% for user in users %}
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'user-detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a></h2>
    {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
     <h2>There are no users loaded yet </h2>
 {% endif %}
```